# Enzyme wrapper.update() causes ref input to no longer have value prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Here is a Code Sandbox that contains a test simulating this issue. The test in this Code Sandbox fails as described in this question: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-jest-and-enzyme-testing-c7vng

---

I'm trying to test the value of an `<input />` that gets updated inside a `useEffect`. This is the code from the Code Sandbox, which is a simplified version of something I'm trying to do in a project.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current.value = "";
    console.log(typeof ref.current.value);
  }, [count]);

  const ref = useRef(null);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
    console.log(count);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input ref={ref} type="text" />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>click me</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I use `useRef` to set the value of the `<input />`.

The `useEffect` gets called when the `<button />` is clicked. The `<button />` updates the `useState` `count`. `useEffect` is watching updates to `count`, and it gets called as a side-effect.

In the `useEffect`, I set `ref.current.value` to an empty string, and then I log the `typeof` this value to verify that it's a string.

In the test, I try to simulate this behavior:

```
describe("App", () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<App />);
  wrapper.find("input").props().value = "hello";
  act(() =>
    wrapper
      .find("button")
      .props()
      .onClick()
  );
  console.log(wrapper.find("input").debug());
  wrapper.update();
  console.log(wrapper.find("input").debug());
  expect(wrapper.find("input").length).toBe(1);
  expect(wrapper.find("input").props().value).toBe("hello");
});
```

I set the `value` prop to `'hello'`. I then invoke the `<button />` `onClick` prop, effectively clicking it. I then call `wrapper.update()`, and I also `debug()` log the `<input />` before and after `update()`.

Before, `update()`, the `<input />` has a `value` prop containing `'hello'`. After the `update()`, the `<input />` does not have a `value` prop. This causes the test to fail, saying that the `<input />` `value` is undefined after the update.

Shouldn't the input's value be `''` after the update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a list of issues with the current way:

- `<input ref={ref} type="text" />` is describes a [React Element](https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#elements) and has no value prop
- Prop value should be controlled via state and not mutated directly

  ```
  wrapper.find("input").props().value = "hello";
  ```
- Setting value on a DOM Node isn't the same as setting a prop value. Using React means that you ceed DOM manipulation to it.
  `useRef` allows for access to the underlying DOM Node when passed an initial value of `null` and this following line mutates DOM in spite of `App` state.

  ```
  ref.current.value = "";
  ```

In certain scenarios, it's expedient to manipulate DOM in spite of the App state. The tests should then deal with the DOM Node and check changes to it.

```
describe("App", () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<App />);
  wrapper.find("input").getDOMNode().value = "hello";
  act(() =>
    wrapper
      .find("button")
      .props()
      .onClick()
  );
  wrapper.update();
  expect(wrapper.find("input").length).toBe(1);
  expect(wrapper.find("input").getDOMNode().value).toBe("");
});
```

If you consider that your use case doesn't require this much of a direct control of the DOMNode. 
The `input` element value prop can be controlled with state. For example,

```
const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [value, setValue] = useState("hello");
  useEffect(() => {
    setValue("");
  }, [count]);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={value} />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>click me</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. As to `wrapper.find("input").props().value = "hello";`, as far as I know, this is the recommended way to test props in Enzyme.

Comment: This is very helpful. Thanks